# Writing an impex to change the HMC Login attribute to enabled for all employees

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have the current problem that many of my employees in Hybris have the HMC login attribute set to inherit from group, which means that they can't log in to the HMC. This was due to that I used an impex script that set new users to this a while ago. I try now to write an impex script that updates all employees to have HMC access instead. I found the `<ignore>` tag to be interesting on the Wiki which states that "There is a special value  that makes the ImpEx skip the entry and leave the item value at the one it currently is." (https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/ImpEx+Syntax). So when I am trying to use the following script:

```
UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];password;description;name;groups(uid);sessionLanguage(isocode);sessionCurrency(isocode);hmcLoginDisabled[default=false]
;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>
```

I think it should ignore all current values and set hmcLoginDisabled to false. But HAC gives me the following output:

```
UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];password;description;name;groups(uid);sessionLanguage(isocode);sessionCurrency(isocode);hmcLoginDisabled[default=false]
,,no existing item found for update;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>


27.03.2014 15:26:38: ERROR: line 3 at main script: Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 1 lines!
27.03.2014 15:26:38: ERROR: line 3 at main script: Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 1 lines!
```

Anyone that has any idea on how to write an impex script to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just considered Nevins post and came up with this final solution that actually worked:

```
UPDATE Employee[batchmode=true];itemtype(code)[unique=true];hmcLoginDisabled[default=false]
;Employee
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just leave the fields blank if you don't want to update the value.

Comment: You can omit entire columns as well, if it's easy. A good place to learn about impex is by decompiling some of the `core` code.